# jQuery function starts before click, why?

Tags: javascript, jquery, click, transition

So I'm making a simple box rotate using jquery and [jquery.transit](http://ricostacruz.com/jquery.transit/).

I'm working with a basic `.click` function which calls another named function. However the named function executes before I click the button (immediately as the page loads) and I was wondering why this is happening and how can I fix this?

Here is a jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/kdLSS/1/

My code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <style>
    div {
      background-color:yellow;
      width:100px;
      border:1px solid blue;
      position:absolute;
      left:50px;
    }
  </style>
  <script src='http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.0/jquery.min.js'></script>
  <script src='jquerytransit.js'></script> 
  <title>test</title>
</head>
<body>
  <script>
    $(function() {
      function hello() {
        $("#block").transition({
          perspective: '0px',
          rotateY: '180deg'
        }, 100 );
      }

      $("#go").click(hello())
    });
  </script>
  <button id="go"> Run</button>
  <div id="block">Hello!</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Thanks so much and happy thanksgiving for those in the states!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Fix your event handler assignment. It should be:

```
$("#go").click(hello);

// not $("#go").click(hello());
```

You want to pass a reference to the `hello` function. You don't want to pass it the result of the `hello` function.

Comment: Now how will the function be invoked ?

Comment: @sheldonCooper: The browser will invoke the function when the element is clicked. The `.click` method does not invoke the function. It merely registers what to do when an event happens. Which is why it wants a function reference.

Answer (score 1):

In javascript, adding () behind a function name executes that function immediately. You want to assign a function to the click event obmit the ()

i.e.

```
 $("#go").click(hello);
```

Then that function will be executed when #go is clicked

Answer (score 0):

@Le Marcin

There are some basic mistakes that you have done.Like you have return your `function hello` within the `document.ready` and have not closed the brackets correctly. So it is being treated to run once your `Dom` is ready.

Corrected Script.

```
$(function() {
    $("#go").click(function() {
        hello();
        alert("Hi")
     });
 });

function hello()
{
    $("#block").transition({ perspective: '0px',
    rotateY: '180deg' }, 5000 );
}​
```